# How to change AngularJS ui-bootstrap date picker starting day

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is there a way to change the starting day for the ui-bootstrap date picker for AngularJS?  At the moment, from left to right, the days starts Monday and ends on Sunday, and I would like the days to start on Saturday and end on Friday.
Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hq59lB3Im88nZAhJdmUT?p=preview)

```
<p class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
      </span>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already assign startingDay, put it to 6 and it will start on saturday.